# (python) how to save ranges of laser scan related to each time stamp?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

I have a python problem.
I want to save the output of msg.ranges in a csv file. actually i want to have a csv file that in the first column time stamp are saved, and in the second column ranges. i run a bag file. so for each timestamp i will have its realted ranges.

```
rosmsg show sensor_msgs/LaserScan 
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
float32 angle_min
float32 angle_max
float32 angle_increment
float32 time_increment
float32 scan_time
float32 range_min
float32 range_max
float32[] ranges
float32[] intensities
```

would you please guide me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404958/(python)-how-to-save-ranges-of-laser-scan-related-to-each-time-stamp?!/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to downgrade it to Kinetic, but overall scripts should be usable:

- https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/rosbag_to_csv

> `rosbag_to_csv`
>
> A GUI tool to convert topics from a
> single rosbag file or multiple rosbag
> files at once to csv files

Don't use GUI, but the scripts inside - overall, you can install a virtual machine with ROS Noetic and use it directly here with your bags.

[In these answers here](https://answers.ros.org/question/55037/is-there-a-way-to-save-all-rosbag-data-into-a-csv-or-text-file/) you have other options to use:

- `rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic`

where flags:

`-b` - display messages in a bag file.

`-p` display messages in a matlab/octave-friendly plotting format.

- `rosbag play mybag.bag` and then `rostopic echo /foo > output.txt` + modify it with e.g. Python pandas library

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1